# XPath 2.0: How to implement a map/hash/associative_array

Tags: dictionary, xpath, hashmap, associative-array, xpath-2.0

I have a xpath 2.0 expression that implements a map/hash/associative_array:

```
if ($mykey eq 'key1') then 'val1'  
else if ($mykey eq 'key2') then 'val2'  
else if ($mykey eq 'key3') then 'val3'  
else if ($mykey eq 'key4') then 'val4'  
...
(same for 50 key/value pairs)
```

**Is there a more compact way to do it?** (the map is part of a longer xpath expression)

I have tried some tricks by assigning the sequence of pairs to a variable:

```
for $seq in ('key1', 'val1', 'key2', 'val2' ...) return
    <some trick to access only keys and then the associated value>
```

but it doesn't assign the sequence to `$seq`, it loops over each value in the sequence.

---

**Update: Solved:** I'm using proposal #1 by Jens Erat: Create an external xml with the mapping. For example, for this xml (cfg.xml):

```
<cfg>
    <map>
        <key1>val1</key1>
        <key2>val2</key2>
        <key3>val3</key3>
        ...
    </map>
</cfg>
```

the xpath will be:

```
doc('cfg.xml')/cfg/map/*[ name() eq $mykey ]
```

Note: If key1, key2, etc start with a digit, just add a non digit char (for example "k") in the xml, and modify the xpath acordingly:

```
doc('cfg.xml')/cfg/map/*[ name() eq concat('k',$mykey) ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several proposals:

1. Probably the most reasonable way would be to put the data into some XML document with a key/value pairing and just query this document.
2. An obvious, but rather hacky-ish solution would be to use string manipulation, eg.

   ```
   substring-after(('key1:val1', 'key2:val2')[starts-with(concat($key, ':'))], ':')
   ```
3. Using `index-of`. In XQuery, you would do something like

   ```
   let $seq := ('key1', 'val1', 'key2', 'val2')
   let $key := 'key1'
   return $seq[index-of($seq, $key) + 1]
   ```

   But in XPath 2.0, no `let` is allowed, and the `for` hack doesn't work with sequences. You will have to repeat the sequence:

   ```
   ('key1', 'val1', 'key2', 'val2')[index-of(('key1', 'val1', 'key2', 'val2'), 'key1') + 1]
   ```

   But then splitting into two sequences would probably be more reasonable:

   ```
   ('val1', 'val2')[index-of(('key1', 'key2'), 'key1')]
   ```

Comment: If you had access to XPath 3.0 or XQuery 1.0 or 3.0, you could write your own map implementation using a couple of functions and manipulating an XML document of key value pairs.

Comment: Jens: I don't like 1st one because it requires adding a new file (xml), and I don't like the 3rd one because it requires repetition of the key/value pair list, or requires separating the list of keys and the list of values (so you loose track of the pairs for 50 pairs). So I have tried the 2nd one, but it doesn't work, because the starts-with() function requires two parameters (it is not a context function). Probably the solution would be to repeat the list of key/value pairs as a parameter to the function, but it would convert the 2nd proposal into a bad solution. I will try the 1st proposal.

Comment: adamretter: The Xpath expression will be an assertion into a XSD 1.1 document, so only XPATH 2.0 is available. I'm trying Jen's 1st proposal.

Comment: I'm using Jens Erat's proposal #1. See the "Update" section at the question.